# Prove that a nontrivial quadrangulation cannot have two adjacent vertices with degree 2 in one quadrilateral

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Given a planar quadrangulation $Q$ I am trying to show that there cannot exist two adjacent vertices in any quadrilateral of the quadrangulation that are both of degree 2 (we will label these vertices as $v_1$ and $v_2$). I am not taking into consideration just a simple $4$-cycle, rather I am considering quadrangulations of 5 or more vertices.

My idea is the following: assume that there exists a quadrangulation of 5 or more vertices that contains two adjacent vertices, both of degree 2. By definition, this quadrangulation must contain a $4$-cycle as a subgraph. Then it seems like we cannot join this subgraph with only one vertex to create another subgraph of said quadrangulation, because this would have to contain one of these vertices of degree 2. Thus we must add at least two new vertices, both of which are now adjacent with the two vertices that are allowed to have more than 2 neighbors. However, now this is not a quadrangulation, because the outer face is incident with 6 distinct vertices. I am quite sure one would need some type of a recursive argument here. It would be nice to have a general proof for this, not necessarily considering several different cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $x,y$ are two adjacent vertices of degree $2$. Let $w$ be $x$'s other neighbor, and let $z$ be $y$'s other neighbor, so that we have a path $(w,x,y,z)$. We cannot have $w=z$, because then we'd get an odd cycle, and all quadrangulations are bipartite graphs.

On either side of edge $xy$, we have a face whose boundary includes at least the edges $wx, xy, yz$. All faces must have length $4$, and the only fourth edge that can complete this path to a cycle is the edge $wz$. So the edge $wz$ must exist, and the four edges $wx, xy, yz, zw$ must form the boundary of this face.

There's *two* such faces on the two different sides of edge $xy$, so we have two faces that have these four edges as a boundary. Therefore the graph is a $4$-cycle, and two adjacent vertices of degree $2$ cannot exist in any larger quadrangulation.

Comment: Nice! This leads me to a question of what is the upper bound on the 2-degree vertices of a quadrangulation? Furthermore, is there a tight bound?

Comment: It would be very hard to do better than how many there are in $K_{2,n}$.

Comment: That's right.  I just want to consider the upper (lower) bound of the number of vertices of degree 3 in 3-connected  quadrangulations, now I realized that there could be an infinite number of 3-regular quadrangulations, and therefore considering the upper bound doesn't have much significance. But how about the lower bound? Is "1"?